# How to specify global sshkit limit in capistrano deploy.rb file

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

by default it's :parallel, which causes much troubles when there were many hosts.

I found that sshkit has an option called limit, but did not find how to set it globally.

Answer (score 1):

```
module SSHKit
  class Coordinator
    private
      def default_options
        { in: :groups, limit: 5 }
      end
  end
end
```

adding a monkey patch into deploy.rb did the trick, no neat